# C++: How to keep common code path for multiple overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Does anyone know how I can keep the code in `swap_1()` and `swap_2()` common?  I'm a bit confused how to do that because the referencing of the argument types are different.

```
// overload the function call
template<class T> void swap_1(T&& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp {move(a)};
    a = move(b);
    b = move(tmp); 
}

template<class T> void swap_1(T& a, T&& b)
{
    T tmp {move(a)};
    a = move(b);
    b = move(tmp); 
}

void f1()
{
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};

    swap_1(v, vector<int>{4, 5, 6});
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of these overloads are. You could just do `v = vector<int>{4, 5, 6};`.

Comment: To invoke the rvalue/move assignment operator and rvalue/move copy constructor.

Comment: [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a third template and call it from the other templates:

```
template<class T, class U>
void swap(T&& a, U&& b)
{
    typename std::remove_reference<T>::type tmp {std::move(a)};
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp); 
}

// overload the function call
template<class T>
void swap_1(T&& a, T& b)
{
    swap(std::forward<T>(a), b);
}

template<class T>
void swap_1(T& a, T&& b)
{
    swap(a, std::forward<T>(b));
}
```

Remember that `T &&a` is a universal reference, not an R-value reference. You could even replace both functions with

```
template<class T, class U, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, typename std::remove_reference<U>::type>::value>::type>
void swap_1(T&& a, U&& b)
{
    typename std::remove_reference<T>::type tmp {std::move(a)};
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp); 
}
```

You tagged the question with C++11. With newer versions of C++ you can write it a bit simpler. This is a shorter C++14 version:

```
template<class T, class U, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_reference_t<T>, std::remove_reference_t<U>>::value>>
void swap_1(T&& a, U&& b)
{
    std::remove_reference_t<T> tmp {std::move(a)};
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp); 
}
```

Comment: I added the newer C++17 standard tag as well to see the newer method (although I'm interested in C++11 due to older compilers). Thanks

Comment: Needs typename in from of std::remove_reference

Comment: I understand forward(), but am stuck on remove_reference.  Why is remove_reference required?  Actually, it seems to have the same behavior with remove_reference removed.

Comment: @notaorb Yes, you are right. I fixed it. With C++17 you can use `std::remove_reference<T>` instead of `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type`

Comment: I was referring to adding typename in the first example.  Haven't tried your second one yet.

Comment: @notaorb You need remove_reference because `std::is_same` returns false for `std::vector<int> &` and `std::vector<int> &&`.

Comment: In regards to remove_reference, advice taken for your second example.  I'm still only looking at the first one with remove_reference.

Comment: @notaorb I did the forwarding wrong in the first code. You don't forward L value references. You only forward universal references. But then you need `remove_reference`. Now it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks.  First example is understood.  I'm looking at the C++14 version.  Can you comment on use of enable_if_t and remove_reference?  I remove that code and it appears the appropriate move/rvalue assignment is working.

Comment: @notaorb This code checks that `T` and `U` are the same type.

Comment: Is forward() not required for both arguments in all cases and remove remove_reference?  It is equiv to static_cast<T&&>(x).  Ref collapses as follows T = int -> T&& = int&&, T = int& -> T&& = int & && = int&, T = int&& -> T&& = int&& && = int &&

Comment: I'm looking at the cast rules in Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 196 Title: References to References.

Comment: @notaorb I tried it in my posted code and `std::forward` made a R-value reference from a L-value reference that was passed as `T &a` but it didn't change a L-value reference that was passed as `T &&a`. If you pass a L-value reference to `T &a` the type `T` is the type without reference (e.g. `int`). `std::forward<T>(a)` returns a R-value reference. If you pass a L-value reference to `T &&a` the type of `T` is a reference (e.g. `int &`). `std::forward<T>(a)` returns a L-value reference.

Comment: how are you debugging whether an L or R value reference is being passed?

Comment: @notaorb Create a function with two overloads: `void f(int &);` and `void f(int &&);`. If the first function is called you have an L-value reference and if the second function is called it's an R-value reference.

Comment: Thanks that helped.  You're correct on how forward() works in your last comment. Regarding 1st C++11 example: Why is remove_reference required?  I'm having trouble with that and tested without remove_reference and that works.  Thanks

Comment: @notaorb You can't move into a reference. You need the pure type.

Comment: thanks found need for remove_reference through the compiler.  I'm curious why it's not required for parameters a & b.